# Забрать url из текста

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Регуляркой забираю https из текста, но бывает попадаются и такие ссылки как: `vk.cc/ciFcBd`  `www.lamoda.ru/s/6oJc67/` `sokolov.ru/promo/formula-for-me/`

```
text = post['text']
link = (re.findall(r'https?://\S+', text))
```

Comment: а вопрос в чем? как определить ссылка это или нет? достаточно сложно, одной регуляркой достоверно обойтись не выйдет :)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Может регуляркой можно найти .сс .ru .com

Comment: можно, а такое например это ссылка? java.github.cc.lang.ru ? или имя пакета импортируемого? Одной только регуляркой вы будете ловить всё подряд, если вас это устраивает то группы => ```()``` и "или" => ```|```

Comment: @Владимир Клыков в моем случае такого в тексте не найдется

Comment: Ну тогда ответ выше, используйте ```группировку``` и ```или```, и ваша регулярка сможет реагировать на разные паттерны :) ```(https?://\S+)|(еще что то)|(еще чегонибудь)```

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Сможете это дать в ответе на три эти ссылки. Просто я в регулярках полный 0

Comment: Зачем мне это? я на данный сайт пришел помогать людям учится программировать :) могу помочь иным образом, дать ссылку на статью после прочтения которой вам самому станет не сложно сделать подобное :) чтиво минут на 30, при плохом раскладе на час :)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Окей буду учить регулярки!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760588/how-do-you-extract-a-url-from-a-string-using-python. И еще куча ответов только на этом сайте.