# Передача переменных из txt файла

Tags: python

Возможно ли передать третью переменную? беру их из txt файла в таком формате :

```
lamodaru:215633333
letoile_official:215633333
eccoru:215633333
sokolov.russia:215633333
```

код:

```
with open('/home/admin7/vkbot5/script2/lp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for el in f.read().splitlines():
        group_name, group_id1 = el.split(':')
        group_id = int(f"{group_id1}")
```

Comment: Я так понимаю если напишу что это можно сделать одной [регуляркой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479348/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-url-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0) буду послан лесом?) ну да ладно xD

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Не в обиду это серьезно можно сделать регуляркой ? Честно я уже устал как будто пол программирования состоит из регулярных выражений!!

Comment: вполне, одна из фишек [групп](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-groups)  то что их можно именовать и забрать значения в виде ассоциативного массива "ключ" => "значение" именно в том формате что вы пытаетесь забрать :)

Comment: Нет, далеко не всё, но инструмент очень полезен в задачах разбора, парсинга, поиска и многих иных, но иногда можно перебарщивать решая такие задачи как у вас в этом вопросе регуляркой(как стрелять из пушки по воробьям, т.е. можно, но не самый практичный способ)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Тебя понял!!

Comment: не очень понял вопроса, но если что то такое ```lamodaru:215633333:123123``` то никто не мешает...  ```x = el.split(':'); group_name = x[0]; group_id1 = x[1];.....```

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Это что вроде того как перебрать в цикле логины с паролями только нужно добавить еще третью переменную !

Comment: Ну мой пример вам подходит? там плюс минус почти рабочий код, отформатировать только нормально :)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Окей

Comment: Можно так ещё третий элемент получить `[i.split(':') for i in el.split(' ')][2][1]`

Comment: @DiMithras Не сочтите за грубость! но не могли вы бы дать ответ, как вписать ваш генератор в мой пример ?

Comment: @teamarden тут вопрос поменяли. У вас структура файла всё же какая? По одному id на строку или нескольно id разделённых пробелами как у Вас изначально было? Т.е. 4 id в строке, потом ещё несколько и т.д.?

Comment: @DiMithras Ну, судя по использованию в коде `splitlines` всё-таки имелись в виду отдельные строки. Я поэтому просто привёл форматирование в соответствии с задумкой автора вопроса. Но могу и ошибаться, конечно.

Comment: @CrazyElf я по изначальному сообщению понял, что в каждой строке несколько элементов.

Comment: @CrazyElf Всё верно! И вправду все оказалось проще) Мне аж стыдно  стало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем-то вы переусложнили код, всё немного проще, ну и просто добавляете третью переменную в распаковку переменных из списка и всё:

```
with open('/home/admin7/vkbot5/script2/lp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        group_name, group_id1, something = line.split(':')
        group_id = int(group_id1)
        ...
```